# Libclang don't follow include statement

Tags: c++, opencv, include, clang

I'm trying to use Libclang to programatically analyse the [Opencv](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) library, but when I try to import the main header from Opencv `opencv.hpp`, libclang won't follow the path.

Previously, it was reading everything quite beautifully, but then I figured it was following my `$PATH`'s headers, and I want it to follow these specifics ones.

`opencv.hpp` is a file containing lots of `#include` statements like so:

```
#include "core/core_c.h"
#include "core/core.hpp"
#include "flann/miniflann.hpp"
// ... and so on
```

but, when I try to open it with `libclang`, or either `clang ./opencv.hpp`, it won't follow:

```
clang ./Header_Example/opencv.hpp
./Header_Example/opencv.hpp:46:10: fatal error: 'core/core_c.h' file not found
#include "core/core_c.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

but I'm sure it is on the right directory (a bit of my `tree` output):

```
── Header_Example
│   ├── opencv.hpp
│   ├── opencv2
│   │   ├── # more directories
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   ├── affine.hpp
│   │   │   ├── core.hpp
│   │   │   ├── core_c.h
│   │   │   ├── types_c.h
│   │   │   ├── version.hpp
│   │   │   └── wimage.hpp
```

maybe I'm not using the right `clang` parameters?

A bit of context: I want to analyse Opencv types, classes and functions, this info is present on the headers, so I don't think I would need the full library to read the code. When I tried to use the full library I found myself in trouble. I need to use the iOS compilation(?)version(?) of the library, hence I copy/pasted the headers from the compiled version into this working directory (sorry? :) )

EDIT 1: It may seem odd my directories having this `opencv2/`, but if I remove the headers from inside of it, clang will complain 'bout why aren't they there: `fatal error: 'opencv2/core/types_c.h' file not found`

Comment: Do you give the correct include path to libclang? `-I./opencv2`

Comment: @DanielJour I didn't, but yet, it changes the error as if it didn't found even `opencv2/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to add `-I.` before adding `-I./opencv2` because I had one file one the same directory as `opencv.hpp`. Gosh I feel so stupid for missing this.